# I am getting empty values for sports-title and third

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

- i am new to js.
- can you tell me why I am getting empty values for sports-title and third.
- since we have one div with content in it.
  sports-title---->{"0":{}}
  third---->{}
- providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
findStringInsideDiv() {

   /* 
   var str = document.getElementsByClassName("sports-title").innerHTML;
   */
    var sportsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("sports-title");
    var third = sportsTitle[0];
    var thirdHTML = third.innerHTML



    //str = str.split(" ")[4];
    console.log("sports-title---->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTitle));
        console.log("third---->" + JSON.stringify(third));
    console.log("thirdHTML---->" + JSON.stringify(thirdHTML));


    if ( thirdHTML === " basketball football swimming " ) {

          console.log("matching basketball---->");


      var menu = document.querySelector('.sports');
      menu.classList.add('sports-with-basketball');

      // how to add this class name directly to the first div after body.
      // but we are not rendering that div in accordion
      //is it possible

    }

    else{
    console.log("not matching");
    }

  }
```

Comment: referencing only to object isn't enough you must get text from this object

Comment: @Grisza hello can you tell me why i am seeing 0 in the output ---> {"0":{}}

Comment: what do you expect to see in `sportsTitle` and `third`?

Comment: What's the reason 0 coming there??

Comment: Since I don't see 0 in my code

Comment: because with getElementsByClassName you getting array and thus "0" and when I typed without JSON.stringify I got `sports-title---->[object HTMLCollection]`

Comment: Is 0 index or value??

Comment: 0 is index it is the key

Answer (score 1):

When you call an object in the Document Object Model (DOM) using any of the GetElement selectors, it returns an object that can be considered that HTML element. This object includes much more than just the text included in the HTML element. In order to access the text of that element, you want to use the .textContent property.

In addition, an HTML class can potentially be assigned to several elements and therefore GetElementsByClassName returns an array so you would have to do the following, for example:

```
console.log("sports-title---->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTitle[0].textContent));
```

You can find a brief introduction to the DOM on the W3Schools Website. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp If you follow along it gives an overview of different aspects of the DOM including elements.

Comment: R  hello can you tell me why i am seeing 0 in the output ---> {"0":{}}

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName

Comment: Thank you for catching that, @Grisza!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpful
As you see `sportsTitle[0].textContent` returns full heading and 0 is the index thus you get "0" when you stringify (serialize) `sportsTitle`. Why 0? Because you have one `<h1>` element . See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cqj6g7f0/3/
 I added second h1 and see the `console.log` and you get two indexes 0 and 1

if you want to get a word from  element so get substring use `substr()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

One way is to change `<h1>` class attr to id and do `sportsTitle.textContent;`
and use `substr()` on this string
or
2nd way is to remain class attr and do `sportsTitle[0].textContent;`
and `substr()` on this string

The 2nd is the better way